# RAM not showing

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

I've had this problem for over a month now, and I keep trying solutions posted by people on every site I've found, but I still can not figure out what is "using" my RAM.

I have 24GB RAM installed, and it gets detected by Windows fine. When I log in, my RAM is around 25%, and after my programs have finished starting, it is usually around 40-50%. Then, over the next couple of hours, my usage will increase. It will usually stop after around 6 hours at 65%. Overnight, there's about a 50% chance that my computer restarts and takes me to the login page (I am assuming BSOD.) If it did not crash, then my usage is usually around 95%, and will not decrease from there. In the next 6 hours, it is almost guaranteed to crash. I used to be able to let my computer run overnight and it would stay running for weeks, but that suddenly stopped and I got stuck in this loop.

I saw a news page on an invisible Chrome virus and saw that I had almost identical symptoms, so I uninstalled Chrome (I stopped using Chrome and moved to Firefox about 4 months ago - before I had this issue.) This fixed my problem for about a week, then it came back again.

Next, I thought it was a virus. I ran Malwarebytes, BitDefender and HitmanPro, but none of them found anything.

I looked once again at all the threads I found when I looked at this issue earlier, but I still couldn't find anything.

#### Task manager

I went into task manager and checked my processes. In details (Windows 10) I sorted by `Private working set`, and found that the total was less than 4 GB. (At the time of all the following stats, my usage was on 55%.) I also got the [page on memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVWZV.png).

#### RAMMap

I went into RAMMap, and saw the [following summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBoi3.png). I also did the same thing as Task Manager but with the [total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYHjf.png).

#### Process Explorer

I did the same thing with [process explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGkIW.png). For some reason, I could not open the summary for memory with the system information page.

#### Process Hacker

The same with [process hacker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAg9n.png).

#### CleanMem

I tried CleanMem and found that it did reduce my usage by <10%, but it was not able to prevent crashes.

Is there something I'm missing? I've seen some people talk about having high RAM usage isn't a problem unless it makes your computer run slow, but mine is definitely affected, and when it hits about 85% my computer becomes almost unusable.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I did use safe mode overnight and my usage in the morning was 35%.

EDIT 2: Blue Screen View shows [nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ous3.png) (I'm not sure how long the logs stay, but I saw a BSOD myself about a month ago)

Comment: This is my least favorite thing to do, but throughout all of this have you ever started over with a clean system install? Also when you're assuming a BSOD, you can check for dump files or use [BlueScreenView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to see/read the dump files.

Comment: You could also try using safe mode for a day or two just to see what happens.

Comment: @DrZoo Thanks for reminding me, I tested out safe mode, and I had used BSV in the past but completely forgot about it. I added notes on both.

Comment: I believe the logs stay until you delete them. You could check the physical file location to see if any dump files are there.

Comment: C:\Windows\Minidumps is completely empty for some strange reason. Another thing I forgot to mention, sometimes it isn't even a crash, I just get a blank screen and can't do anything. My computer's lights are still on, but any scripts that were running on it stop, so I'm assuming it's basically off, and the only thing I can do it hold the power button and start it back up.